# why the "===" operation do not work on "filter" or "where" do not apply on my TableQuery [slick2]

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

I use slick 2.0.2 and scala, my datamodel is:

```
  case class AdItem(id:Option[Long], res:String,status:String,userId:String, head:String,summary:String, url:String, position:String)
class Advertisement(tag:Tag) extends Table[AdItem](tag, "Advertisement"){
  def id=column[Long]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def res=column[String]("Resource")
  def status=column[String]("Status")
  def userId=column[String]("User")
  def head=column[String]("head")
  def summary=column[String]("Summary")
  def url=column[String]("Ad_Link")
  def position=column[String]("Position")
  def * = (id.?, res, status, userId,  head, summary, url, position)<>(AdItem.tupled, AdItem.unapply)
  def userFK=foreignKey("Ad_USE_FK", userId, userdata)(_.id)
}
```

this is My TableQuery:

```
val addata=TableQuery[Advertisement]
```

when I execute the:

```
val idd="1232232"
addata.filter(_.id === idd.toLong)
```

I get the error is:

```
[error] G:\testprojects\slickplay\app\controllers\AdController.scala:30: value =
== is not a member of scala.slick.lifted.Column[Long]
[error]       addata.filter(_.id === idd.toLong)
```

I follow the instruction of http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.2/queries.html#sorting-and-filtering

I think the "===" can apply the column[Long]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to import the proper implicit conversions:

```
import scala.slick.driver.JdbcDriver.simple._
```

or

```
import scala.slick.driver.TheDriverOfMyChoice.simple._
```